# Could not test Spring Boot Webflux performance with Apache Bench

Tags: spring-boot, apachebench

I met a problem when testing the performance of spring reactive projects with Apache Bench.

```
ab http://localhost:8080/hi
```

The result shows timeout.

But it's OK for `curl http://localhost:8080/hi`

My project uses Spring boot version is 2.0.0.M6. I will paste some of the code.

pom.xml is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

MyRouter.java

```
@Component
public class MyRouter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRouter.class);
    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> router(PersonHandler personHandler) {
        return route(GET("/hi"), request -> ok().body(BodyInserters.fromObject("hello")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to an ab's bug when call netty server.

To workaround it, just add "Connection: closed" into response header. But this is not a final solution.

MyRouter.java

```
@Component
public class MyRouter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRouter.class);
    @Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> router(PersonHandler personHandler) {
        return route(GET("/hi"), request -> ok().header("Connection", "close").body(BodyInserters.fromObject("hello")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Apache bench could not handle the response without Connection: close.
But, if it's a keep/alive request, how to handle?
Really hope the bug could be fixed in the near future.